# Crashes when using gnome tweak tool with Gnome 3.4.1

Tags: gnome, 12.10, gnome-tweak-tool

When i try to luch gnome-tweak-tool from terminal i get

`INFO    : No translated schema for org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences (domain: gsettings-desktop-schemas)
ERROR   : Could not find any typelib for GnomeDesktop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gnome-tweak-tool", line 75, in <module>
    MainWindow()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/mainwindow.py", line 41, in __init__
    model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._model.load_tweaks()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakmodel.py", line 146, in load_tweaks
    mods = __import__("gtweak.tweaks", globals(), locals(), tweak_files, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_typing.py", line 22, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Pango, Gtk, GnomeDesktop
ImportError: cannot import name GnomeDesktop`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error doing

```
apt-get remove gnome-tweak-tool  
apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

And

```
apt-get install gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
```

worked for me

Credits to robytrevi from the portuguese ubuntu forum

Answer (score 0):

Try running as "sudo" unless your missing those dependencies, which I doubt. You need administrator privilidges to run and use ubuntu tweak.